# Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i followed exactly the instructions here http://erlerobotics.com/docs/Simulation/Configuring_your_environment.html , everything went find except the very last command :::

Then compile everything together:

```
cd ~/simulation/ros_catkin_ws    
source devel/setup.bash  catkin_make
```

Error in the terminal :

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object ardupilot_sitl_gazebo_plugin/ardupilot_sitl_gazebo_plugin/CMakeFiles/ardupilot_sitl_gazebo_plugin.dir/src/SocketAPM.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/omaralhebsi/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/libardupilot_sitl_gazebo_plugin.so
[ 98%] Built target ardupilot_sitl_gazebo_plugin
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

What do i have to do ?? , plz help its only one step and then i can start working on Gazebo. I guess the problem is with catkin_make

i ran the code again and this is what i received :

```
 [100%] Built target sitl_test_node
/home/simulation/ros_catkin_ws/src/gazebo_cpp_examples/erle-copter_pattern_follower/src/image_subscriber.cpp:5:25: fatal error: aruco/aruco.h: No such file or directory
 #include <aruco/aruco.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [gazebo_cpp_examples/erle-copter_pattern_follower/CMakeFiles/ros_erle_pattern_follower.dir/src/image_subscriber.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo_cpp_examples/erle-copter_pattern_follower/CMakeFiles/ros_erle_pattern_follower.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232830/invoking-%22make--j2--l2%22-failed/) by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-04-26**:
NO ONE LOOKED AT IT ??

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-04-26**:
I need an answer plz !

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-04-26**:
Do not provide answers that are not answers. Most likely people aren't helping you because they don't know how to help you or they aren't seeing your question because of improperly titled questions or tagging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The primary issue is that `aruco.h` cannot be found. Do you have that file on your system? Where is it at? How did you get it?

I notice that the [gazebo_cpp_examples package.xml](https://github.com/erlerobot/gazebo_cpp_examples/blob/master/erle-copter_pattern_follower/package.xml) declares dependencies on `aruco`. On my system, `rosdep resolve aruco` reveals that this dependency could be provided by the `ros-indigo-aruco` apt-get package. Do you have this package installed, is it available on your system? I also notice the directions you linked don't seem to mention this getting this package either from source or from apt-get. Perhaps it is just a mistake in the directions.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0